# glib-2.48.0 configure syntax code error

Tags: glib

I should probably post this in the glib forums but I want to try here first. I want to update the required dependencies for GTK+. When I start the process with glib-2.48.0 I find that there is no configure file, just `configure.ac`. I ran `autoconf` and the regular configure file is made. When I run that without any added commands, a syntax error is found:

```
./configure: line 2662: syntax error near unexpected token '-Wno-portability'

./configure: line 2662: 'AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE(-Wno-portability 1.11 no-define no-dist-gzip dist-xz tar-ustar)'
```

I have little experience with scripts but I think it has to do with 1.11. I tried removing it from the script but that didn't do anything. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 1:
So I looked at that page that provided the autoconf answer and tried something else. When I did these steps in order:

```
aclocal # Set up an m4 environment

autoconf # Generate configure from configure.ac

automake --add-missing # Generate Makefile.in from Makefile.am

./configure # Generate Makefile from Makefile.in
```

I got the configuration to work EXCEPT to the point where it cannot determine shared library suffix from libtool. Once again, any help would be appreciated.

EDIT 2:
SO I decided to download glib from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.48/ and configuring that went smoothly. Lesson of the day, know your sources.

Comment: Where did you download the source from? The xz tarball at [ftp.gnome.org](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.48/glib-2.48.0.tar.xz) appears to have a working configure script out of the box (at least it appears to run OK on my 14.04 box).

Comment: https://git.gnome.org/browse/glib

Comment: You can answer your own question so that it doesn't show up in the unanswered question queue.

Answer (score 1):

So I decided to download glib from http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.48/ and configuring that went smoothly. Lesson of the day, know your sources.